# shortcuts for Add new projext to current solution in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide

How can I create or customize shortcuts for Add new projext  to current solution  ?

[The operation method is described in the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/tutorial-projects-solutions?view=vs-2019#add-an-item-to-the-project), but it needs to click several times with the mouse, which is very inconvenient.

I'm learning C + +, often writing examples.

I want to have a faster method.

Tried find in Options > Keyboard but could not find action for this.

the keyboard of New Project is Ctrl+Shift+N

However, it cannot be added to the current solution by default, and the settings need to be modified manually.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the shortcut key is`File.AddNewProject`,not `File.NewProject`.